# Grouping Across a Hierarchy

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

**End Goal:** I need to create a financial report that can follow an organization hierarchy but also separate by account type on each level. Ultimately the report will be displayed in crystal reports.

**Problem:** There are several types of accounts (revenue, expense, liability, etc...). There are also several organizational structures, with a maximum depth of 8 levels. Users need to be able to drill down to each level of the structure, and see sub totals for each account type.

Example

#### Highest Level

- Expense

  - CEO
  - Community & Customer Service
  - Corporate
  - Engineering
- Revenue

  - CEO
  - Community & Customer Service
  - Corporate
  - Engineering

#### Level 1 (CEO)

- Revenue

  - WHS
  - OD
- Expense

  - WHS
  - OD

The structure continues until you end at the account level, which are grouped by account type.

The structure is stored in an adjacency model.
Structure Columns: Class_id - Class_Name - Parent_ID

Account Columns:
Account_id, Class_id, Account_Type, Budget, Actual

I have no problem navigating and grouping the hierarchy, but my difficulty comes in the grouping of account types within the hierarchy. Any suggestions for solutions in SQL or CrystalReports would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you want to look into GROUP BY ROLLUP, which produces a report with subtotals by each level of hierachy.

Comment: what is the issue with account type? how account types are related to hierarchy?

Comment: Account Types aren't directly related to the hierarchy. BUT account types need to be grouped on each level of the hierarchy. The problem I ran into when displaying the data in crystal reports was that I could create a group for account type, but then as you descend the hierarchy you get stuck within a certain account type (revenue or expense). What I want to do is descend only the hierarchy, but then group by account type on each level. Perhaps it's more of a crystal reports issue, just trying to brainstorm some ideas.

Comment: does it mean irrespective of account type... you need to see all account types in hierarchy?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to see the groups by account type in each level of the hierarchy. It might be more of a crystal reports issue than sql... I tried presenting the data in a view at the account level (lowest level), with a flattened structure of the hierarchy. Ex row: acc_Id, Acc_type, L1_Id, L2_id, L3_Id, etc. I can easily drill down through the hierarchy using groups on the level_Id columns. My problem has been grouping by account type for each level.